# MYSQL -- Multiple where's not working

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains `Businesses` and I want to query all of the businesses that have a specific name in them, within a series of postcodes.

For example:

`business_name` = `KFC`

`postcode` = `[N1, N17, N18, BN1]

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_name = 'KFC' AND postcode LIKE '%N1%' OR postcode LIKE '%N17%' OR postcode LIKE '%N18%' OR postcode LIKE '%BN1'
```

The issue is that it's bringing back businesses that have this postcode, but have nothing to do with `KFC`.. Can anyone suggest a reason for this and what I should be doing?

Comment: postcode LIKE '%N1%'  will also search N17, N18 so you can reduce that condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_name = 'KFC' AND (postcode LIKE '%N1%' OR postcode LIKE '%N17%' OR postcode LIKE '%N18%' OR postcode LIKE '%BN1')
```